# Помогите с Entity Framework  code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net, entity

Есть 2 модели.
не могу понять почему это поле содержится в `Destination`, а не в `Lodging`

```
public List<Lodging> Lodgings { get; set;}
```

Я так понял это обозначения связей

Объясните, пожалуйста!

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

 -  namespace Model {
        public class Destination
        {
            public int DestinationId { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Country { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
           public List<Lodging> Lodgings { get; set;
       } }

namespace Model
{
    public class Lodging
    {
        public int LodgingId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Owner { get; set; }
        public bool IsResort { get; set; }
        public Destination Destination { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Логично предположить, что это поле содержит список Lodging, которые ссылаются на данный Destination. Т.е. список всего арендуемого жилья, имеющегося в наличии по данному направлению.

Если уж используется Code First, мне кажется, правильно было бы сделать навигационные свойства так:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Model 
{
    public class Destination
    {
        public int DestinationId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public byte[] Photo { get; set; }

        //навигационное свойство-список
        public virtual ICollection<Lodging> Lodgings { get; set;}
    }

    public class Lodging
    {
        public int LodgingId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Owner { get; set; }
        public bool IsResort { get; set; }
        public int DestinationId { get; set; }

        //навигационное свойство
        public virtual Destination Destination { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Вот [здесь](http://andrey.moveax.ru/mvc3-in-depth/) есть цикл статей по ASP.NET MVC, обратите внимание на главу ["Code First и соглашения"](http://andrey.moveax.ru/mvc3-in-depth/entity-framework/03-code-first-conventions/).

Comment: более того, без ключевого слова virtual (как в вопросе) - Lodgings не будут навигационным свойством